# Issues with fullscreen in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, toggle

I'm making a simple menu in Unity 2D. I created a toggle that actives the full screen option. At this point, everything is alright.
Then, I wanted to do the same, but pressing the F11 key. Here starts the problem. When I press F11, the screen becomes in fullsize, but the toggle doesn't activates and vice versa. 
So, I wanted to create a C# script that checks if Screen.fullscreen is true, it activates the toggle, and if it's false, it deactivates it. 
I thonk that this will solve the problem, but no. When I try to press F11 or click on the toggle, the entire window goes crazy. I don't know how to explain it, but the window will start to shake on its own.
I would appreciate if somebody helps me, thank you!

The code of the toggle is this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ToggleScreen : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void togglescreen()
    {
        if(Screen.fullScreen == true)
        {
            Screen.fullScreen = false;
        }

        else
        {
            Screen.fullScreen = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The code of the F11 key is this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FullScreenMode : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F11))
        {
            if (Screen.fullScreen == true)
            {
                Screen.fullScreen = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Screen.fullScreen = true;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

And the code of the activate and deactivate is this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ChangeValue : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Toggle onOffSwitch;

    private void Awake()
    {
        onOffSwitch = GetComponent<Toggle>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        //onOffSwitch.isOn = Screen.fullScreen;
        if(Screen.fullScreen == true)
        {
            onOffSwitch.isOn = true;
        }
        else
        {
            onOffSwitch.isOn = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of an image.

Comment: okay, now I'm going to change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are repeating the `fullScreen` logic in the `ToggleScreen` script and the `FullScreenMode` script. I would combine these (and simplify them) into a `ScreenManager` class:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ScreenManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    Toggle onOffSwitch;

    void Start()
    {
        // Don't forget to attach the Toggle component to this game object
        onOffSwitch = GetComponent<Toggle>(); 

        // Subscribe to onOffSwitch's onValueChanged event handler
        onOffSwitch.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate 
        {
            // delegate method to call when onOffSwitch.onValueChanged is raised.
            ToggleValueChanged(onOffSwitch); 
        });
    }

    public static void ToggleFullScreen(bool updateToggleUI)
    { 
        var toggledValue = !Screen.fullScreen;
        Screen.fullScreen = toggledValue;
        onOffSwitch.isOn = updateToggleUI ? toggledValue : onOffSwitch.isOn;
    }

    void ToggleValueChanged(Toggle change)
    {
        // The toggle was already changed via the UI, don't flip it back
        ToggleFullScreen(false); 
    }
}
```

Then, simply call `ScreenManager.ToggleFullScreen()` in the `FullScreenMode` script's `Update()` method:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class FullScreenMode : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Don't forget to drag the ScreenManager instance to this reference in the inspector
    [Serializable]
    ScreenManager _screenManager;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F11))
        {
            // Change the Toggle UI since this was triggered with F11
            _screenManager.ToggleFullScreen(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely clear how to do it ... I tried to do what you said, but only the full screen is activated only by pressing F11, clicking the toggle is not activated, and also if the full screen is disabled, the toggle continues to indicate that the full screen is activated

Comment: I didn't give you each step as I thought you were already familiar with using a toggle. I'll edit my answer to include the missing pieces.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Toggler
{

bool state = false;

public void ToggleState()
{

    state = !state; // This sets a Boolean value to the opposite of itself

    if (state)
    {

        // State was just toggled on

    }else{

        // State was just toggled off

    }

}

}
```